# Making a Diagram Application

Tags: wpf, drawing, diagram, scene, flowchart

I decided to make an application that like statechart simulation tool or flowchart (such as yEd, MS visio etc.). It will be a diagram scene application. But, I have'nt decided to platform that I will use yet. Which one is suitable for this jobs?

1. Qt,
2. MS WPF,
3. Python
4. Others

Comment: This is an opinion-based question, therefore out of scope for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, I have only WPF platform experience but I'll share my experience in those area.
I worked almost 2 years for developing in desktop application using WPF(I know it was 1~3 millions $ project). and some portion of my job is developing and maintaining diagram based canvas with telerik libraries.

but the first, I want to recommend you to choose your program going to be a .net-based/cross-platform/web-based.

If you choose that you are going to make windows application and those diagram chart, then WPF and telerik may be a one of good choices.

Comment: In WPF, which classes usefull this job?

Comment: @kaernk well, If you choose use WPF, then consider using telerik libraries with some payment. there are `raddiagram` in telerik. so if you choose to use WPF and telerik, then you should customize it with you application model (domain knowledge.) then also you need some xaml job. you should spend lots of time with studying canvas and xaml and telerik diagram concept. if you choose to develop without telerik libraries then I think you should spend more time.